# TCustomRESTRequest.AddFile() tries to convert my filename to an Int64

Tags: rest, delphi

I'm trying to upload a Document to an api.
The Api owner sent me his C# Code to upload a Document :

```
var client = new 
RestClient("hisurl");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
request.AddHeader("v", "4.2");
request.AddHeader("j_token", "histoken");
request.AddFile("file", "/C:/Users/olivm/Documents/QA API Swagger/smartpacte2.pdf","application/.pdf");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

I decided to use the `TCustomRESTRequest.AddFile()` method as well so here is my code :

```
procedure AttachDocument(contract_id : Integer; pathFile : String);
  var 
    RESTClient : TRESTClient;
    RESTRequest : TCustomRESTRequest;
    Response : TCustomRESTResponse;
  begin
    RESTClient := TRESTClient.Create('');
    RESTRequest := TCustomRESTRequest.Create(nil);
    try
      RESTClient.BaseURL := 'myurl';
      RESTRequest.Client := RESTClient;
      RESTRequest.Accept := 'application/json';
      RESTRequest.Params.AddHeader('j_token','mytoken',[poDoNotEncode]);
      RESTRequest.Method := rmPOST;
      RESTRequest.AddFile('file',pathFile);
      RESTRequest.Execute; 
      Response := RESTRequest.Response;
      ShowMessage(Response.Content);
    finally
      RESTRequest.Free;
      RESTClient.Free;
    end;
  end;
```

But this result in a error :

> RUNTIME ERROR : Impossible converting variant of type (UnicodeString) to type (Int64)

In fact, it seems like the `TCustomRESTRequest.AddFile()`method wants my `pathFile` as the first argument and a Int64 as the second one like this :

```
RESTRequest.AddFile(pathFile,0);
```

I also tried this :

```
RESTRequest.AddFile(pathFile,ctAPPLICATION_PDF);
```

But each and every time i get this error from the api :

> {"errors":"no files found"}

Do you have any idea on how to make this work ?Also, have you ever seen this sort of `TCustomRESTRequest.AddFile()`method ?

Comment: Declare `pathFile` as `String` and not as `Variant`. Choosing the latter makes the compiler think you use [the second overload of the documented method](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.AddFile) where the second parameter is an enum, effectively treated as `Int64`. Don't guess, read error messages and documentations. And include all the declarations in your code example.

Comment: Sorry i edited my code with the declaration of my procedure, is there still a problem with how i declare the arguments ?

Comment: Yes, adding which units you use would also help. Is it guaranteed that you use `REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest` and not something else with the same name? Did you even understand you could make this less ambiguous by using the method with 3 parameters?

Comment: I don't know wich units I'm using since I'm working from the software of my company and not from a normal ide. I'm pretty sure I'm using the real `REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest` since previous devs also used it perfectly well. However the `AddFile()` method requires only 2 parameters in the software i'm using.

Comment: Are you sure its still giving the same error, now that you have changed pathFile to string?

Comment: Yes it still does, in fact, my code was as shown currently when i asked this question : it was my mistake for not adding the procedure declaration to enable a better understanding of the issue

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the `TRESTRequest.AddFile` function correctly and you gave it the wrong parameters.
This function is excellent for easily sending a file in a request just by specifying its path on the local drive or storage and its content type (there is a wide list of MIME types).

As you can read in the DocWiki, there are two overloaded versions of this function :

- The first version (with the parameters : File name as string, File path as string, Content type as enumerator) let you send multiple files in the same request, by specifying a unique name in the `AName` parameter for identifying the file within the request content (similar to the ''Name'' attribute in an HTML form's ''Input'' elements), so as you can send multiple files with different content types in the same request without risk of overwriting.
- The second version (with the parameters : File path as string, Content type as enumerator) let you send only one file in the request. And if this function is executed the second time, then previous content is replaced by the new one.

The file name string is its path on the local storage, it is a string.

For specifying the content type, you must write the enumerator parameter like Delphi enumerators : `TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_PDF`

So here is an example of a working call for sending a PDF file :

```
RESTRequest1.AddFile('File1', 'C:\Doc1.pdf', TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_PDF);
```

For further informations, you can check these DocWiki links :

- https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.AddFile
- https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/REST.Types.TRESTContentType